# Shell scripting and using backslashes with back-ticks?

Tags: shell

I'm trying to do some manipulation with Wordpress and I'm trying to write a script for it...

```
# cat /usr/local/uftwf/_wr.sh 
#!/bin/sh
# $Id$
#

table_prefix=`grep ^\$table_prefix wp-config.php | awk -F\' '{print $2}'`
echo $table_prefix
#
```

Yet I'm getting following output

```
# /usr/local/uftwf/_wr.sh 
 ABSPATH ABSPATH wp-settings.php_KEY LOGGED_IN_KEY NONCE_KEY AUTH_SALT SECURE_AUTH_SALT LOGGED_IN_SALT NONCE_SALT wp_0zw2h5_ de_DE WPLANG WP_DEBUG s all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
#
```

Running from command line, I get the correct output that I'm looking for:

```
# grep ^\$table_prefix wp-config.php | awk -F\' '{print $2}'
wp_0zw2h5_
#
```

What is going wrong in the script?

Comment: What are the input lines look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `grep` command:

```
table_prefix=`grep ^\$table_prefix wp-config.php | awk -F\' '{print $2}'`
```

It either needs three backslashes - not one - or you need to use single quotes (which is much simpler):

```
table_prefix=$(grep '^$table_prefix' wp-config.php | awk -F"'" '{print $2}')
```

It's also worth using the `$( ... )` notation in general.

The trouble is that the backquotes removes the backslash, so the shell variable is evaluated, and what's passed to `grep` is, most likely, just `^`, and each line starts with a beginning of line.

Comment: using \\\ helped, I'll try using $(...) later too

Comment: Another trick is to use a character class `[$]` in place of `\$` or `\\\$` or whatever.  But, on the whole, I would use the single-quoted version.  That only gets messy when you need to match single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
#!/bin/sh

table_prefix=$(awk -F"'" '/^\$table_prefix/{print $2}' wp-config.php)
echo $table_prefix
```

Comment: I like yours better and it works through shell, but same problem as mine as soon as I put inside of a file and run it that file it doesn't work same as running in shell

Answer (score 1):

Does this one work for you?

```
 awk -F\' '/^\$table_prefix/ {print $2}' wp-config.php
```

#### Update

If you are using shell scripting, there is no need to call up awk, grep:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read varName op varValue theRest
do
    if [ "_$varName" = "_\$table_prefix" ]
    then
        table_prefix=${varValue//\'/}   # Remove the single quotes
        table_prefix=${table_prefix/;/} # Remove the semicolon
        break
    fi
done < wp-config.php

echo "Found: $table_prefix"
```

Comment: same thing for your line, it works as stand alone line that executed from shell itself, but doesn't work when it run through shell script file

Comment: Hai Vu, that will doesn't work if the "=" operator touch the string, like in this case : `$table_prefix='foo_';`

Comment: @sputnick: the equal sign must be surrounded by spaces

Comment: @alexus: I tested both of my solutions (awk and shell-only) under Mac OS X Snow Leopard, Red Hat (version?), and Linux Mint 12. They all work, so the problem is somewhere else and I don't have access to your system to help.

Answer (score 1):

This has all the appearance as though the grep is not omitting all the lines that are not matching, when you issue the `echo $table_prefix` without quotes it collapses all the white space into a single output line, if you issue an: `echo "$table_prefix"`, you would see the match with all the other white-space that was output.

I'd recommend the following sed expression instead:

```
table_prefix=$(sed -n "s/^\$table_prefix.*'\([^']*\)'.*/\1/p" wp-config.php)
```